# How to pause timer once its created flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm using a [timer countdown library](https://pub.dev/packages/timer_count_down) but it immediatly starts counting down once the widget it created.
I have a controller for it which has a `.pause()` method which works.
How would I call the pause function right after the widgets creation?

Ex: How could I pause it immediately?

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final CountdownController controller = CountdownController();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Countdown(
      controller: controller, // controller.pause() would pause it
      seconds: 20,
      build: (context, double time) => Text(time.toString()),
      interval: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
      onFinished: () {
        print('Timer is done!');
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That library doesn't have a feature to disallow auto-start, but you could implement something outside the library to achieve a similar effect.

You could convert your stateless widget into a stateful one and use a flag to build a plain text if countdown is not started and build the countdown otherwise.

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  bool started = false;
  final CountdownController controller = CountdownController();
  final int seconds = 20;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return !_started //< ==== When you set this to true, countdown will start
        ? Text(seconds)
        : Countdown(
            controller: controller,
            seconds: seconds,
            build: (context, double time) => Text(time.toString()),
            interval: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
            onFinished: () {
              print('Timer is done!');
            },
          );
  }
}
```

Somewhere in the code you will need to have (maybe as a callback for a button pressed)

```
setState(() => started = true);
```

Comment: I ended up changing the library a bit. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: That's another option that came to my mind... but I thought this was simpler. Definitively a valid option... you might want to suggest the owner to incorporate that trough a pull request.